# how to search git history (pickaxe), but excluding renames

Tags: git, git-log

In a personal project of mine, I renamed a file about 4 times across 4 different commits. In fact, I was learning git with this process as well, and I have renamed many files many, many times.

I want to search for any change involving the word "water", but I do not want git to display every instance "water" that simply results because of file renaming I did.

Answer (score 3):

So I just found the answer. To search for "water" without including file renames:

```
git log -SWater -M
```